# No completion for 'ros2 run' in zsh

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed 'Ros2-Galactic' via `apt` and added the`source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.zsh` to my '.zshrc'. I found that there is no completion for 'ros2 run', 'ros2 pkg', and so on. (I mean no completion for the package_names , topic_names, etc) However the 'ros2' completion works just fine in bash. Later, I've also tried to install via binary package from https://github.com/ros2/ros2/releases. This time, the completion functioned in zsh after sourcing the 'setup.zsh' from the downloaded package. The 'setup.zsh' from this two installation methods are totally different which really confused me.

I'm now using the apt-installed ros2. Wanna know if there is any solution to bring completion for 'ros2' to zsh.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394021/no-completion-for-%27ros2-run%27-in-zsh/) by [Soap-Shampoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/93199/soap-shampoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/534). Someone found a workaround [here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/534#issuecomment-957516107).
Basically you can run the following to re-enable the autocomplete.

```
# argcomplete for ros2 & colcon
eval "$(register-python-argcomplete3 ros2)"
eval "$(register-python-argcomplete3 colcon)"
```

---

Originally posted by [Maxime](https://answers.ros.org/users/84773/maxime/) with karma: 96 on 2022-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Soap-Shampoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/93199/soap-shampoo/) on 2022-01-11**:
Thanks!!! The autocompletion works after I adding the lines above right after `source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.zsh`  to my `.zshrc`. Wonder if this issue still exists in the latest release of ros2-foxy?

Comment: Inspired by `source <(kubectl completion bash)`, above can be used without _eval_ for anyone interested: `source <(register-python-argcomplete3 ros2); source <(register-python-argcomplete3 colcon)`.